# soapui trial version , feeding request with text file

Tags: soapui

I have a very simple soap request with a variable parameter.
I need to run the request taking the variable parameter from a 500 lines text file.
I have no idea about groovy languaje.
I know I achieve  with pro version of soapui but I dont have it.

Is there some guide out there ? 
Cheers.

Comment: Are you using REST API? Are you trying to do data driven tests?

Comment: Im using soapui to send soap requests to a web service (nu soap on the server side). Yes im trying to do data driven tests ... but using trial version. do you know how to do it ? do you know other software to do it ? Thanks.